# Yii: How to send JMultiSelect widget selected value to controller

Tags: yii, controller, widget, multi-select, ajax-request

I have used a widget JMultiSelect and i want the value i selected will be send to the controller when i press an ajax button (ajax request). I would prefer the value will be added in the 'data' of my request.

this is my widget:

```
$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
     'id' => 'Music'
));

$this->widget('ext.multiselect.JMultiSelect', array (
     'id'=>'MusicName',
     'name'=>'Music',
     'data' => $music,
     'options'=> array('header'=>'Select a music file', 'noneSelectedText'=>'Select a music file', 'multiple'=>false),
));

$this->endWidget();
```

i tried something like this:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
      'Test request',
      array('video/createVideo'),
      array(  
         'update'=>'#req_res',
         'data'=> array(
                      'musicFile'=>'js:function(){
                            return document.getElementById("Music").value;
                       }',
          ),                                                    
         'type' => 'post',
      )
);
```

found a solution, but now i have value instead of text:

```
'musicFile'=>'js:function(){
                                                                    return $("#MusicName").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
                                                                    return this.value;    
                                                                }).get();
                                                            }',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this use Js function directly in the data part of ajax

```
$this->widget('ext.multiselect.JMultiSelect', array (
                                            'name'=>'Music',
                                            'data' =>array( 
                                            "urVariableName" = "js: $('#music').val();"
                                           ),
                                            'options'=> array('header'=>'Select a music file', 'noneSelectedText'=>'Select a music file', 'multiple'=>false),
                                    ));
```

To get the data at controller u use POST or GET like as shown

```
$variable=$_POST['urVariableName'];
```

Try using Ajax  button as shown

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton(
      'Test request',
      array('video/createVideo'),
      array(  
         'update'=>'#req_res',
         'data'=> array(
                      'musicFile'=>"js: $('#music').val();"
                      }',
          ),                                                    
         'type' => 'post',
      )
);
```

Comment: the multiselect dropdown is filled. but i don't know how to get the value sended to the controller when i use u ajax request to send all my data on the page.

Comment: the data in the widget will be filled with strings (or music file names from $music). i want the selected from that list being sended. i'll update my second code part

Comment: yes, i want to know what option is selected and send it to controller

Comment: I found solution for it. i only get the selected value instead of text.

Comment: I have added another answer hope it may help u in another situation

Comment: What did u do can u share ??

Comment: I posted it with my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'select' attribute  in the JMultiSelect as shown

```
$this->widget('ext.multiselect.JMultiSelect', array (
     'name'=>'Music',
     'data' => $music,
     'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                                            // $("#my_keyword_id").val(ui.item.id);
                                             alert($("#music").val());
                                                }',
     'options'=> array('header'=>'Select a music file', 'noneSelectedText'=>'Select a music file', 'multiple'=>false),
));
```